# Should I close other programs as I pay bills?

Tags: web-browser, banks

In my country, I can pay bills via Internet bank. Is it preferable to close any other softwares than browser if I pay bills or does it matter if some other programs or browser tabs are on while paying?

Comment: If another app on your computer is malicious then "closing" it won't have any effect as nothing prevents it from appearing closed while still doing evil stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main risk you are wary about is "Cross Site Request Forgery". It used to be a big risk until most frameworks started including defenses against it using an anti-CSRF token / technique with/in their session cookies. There are a few other risks for which it won't matter whether tabs are open or not (HTTP-Only Cookies with Secure flag).

That's the theory. Your actual risk depends on whether your bank implements these security protections in their Internet Banking software.

Checking whether they use some of these is not too difficult (e.g., OWASP ZAP reports on the use of secure cookies). Yes, if you want to be sure, you could close other browser tabs. You should know that it would still leave out a few risks.

Comment: How would closing any other tabs or applications protect against CSRF? It's an attack based on having cookies for your bank stored in the browser, which would not be affected by those measures, and wouldn't likely happen during the time you're doing banking anyways.

Comment: I understand the original question to be "I open an online banking session. Will a program currently running in other open tabs be able to exploit it?". 

For this context, closing the tabs is useful.

However, your point is valid w.r.t. CSRF. Closing tabs is not sufficient. Logging out first (so that the sessions are made invalid) - and then closing the tabs is a minimum necessity. 

Thank for the opportunity to clear my own thinking in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Good practice for your case is to use second browser which will be only for things related to something sensitive as it is using on-line bank.

You can go even deeper by using virtual machine or clean machine which is not meant to be for everyday usage.